# How to get the value from a Template Column in a WPF DataGrid.

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I got a data grid which includes a check box column. I made a modification to that form by using a multiselect checkbox to check all rows at once. And it worked. but i was unable to get the value from that checkbox column when the app is running because i was not sure how to access the data column. can anyone help me with a way to get the check box value (true/false).
This is what i did so far.

[image]
Code: xaml

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path= Id}" Header="Id" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path= Category}" Header="Category" Width="320"/>
            <!--<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path= Check}" Width="*"/>-->

            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="headerCheckBox" />
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Name="chkSelectAll" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=headerCheckBox, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Code: C#

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ÇategoryData CD = (ÇategoryData)datagridview.Items[i];
                if (CD.Check == true)
                {
                    //it always returns false even checked 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are many things kind of weird in my opinion.
I don't really get why your rows' Checkbox is called "chkSelectAll"
I suggest you try to get the following: Each Checkbox can be Checked,UnChecked by themself. When you hit the Headers Checkbox, then all Columns Checkbox get the same State (Checked if at least one was unchecked, and Unchecked if ALL Rows Checkboxes were checked).

If that is right, than you should do the following:
As Siderite Zackwehdex mentioned (I thing that he meant that), you should bind the Checkbox IsChecked Value to a Property of the underlying ViewModel of the Row.

Than your Headers Checkbox should be also bind to a Property of the Viewmodel which holds the Observable Collection like the following:

```
public bool AllSelected
{
    get { return !this.MyCollection.Any(item => !item.IsSelected); }
    set
    {
        var toggle = this.MyCollection.Any(item => !item.IsSelected);
        foreach (var itm in this.MyCollection.Where(item => item.IsSelected != toggle))
            itm.IsSelected = toggle;
    }
}
```

The IsSelected-Property-Setter of the Collections Items-ViewModel MUST notify the ParentViewModel (which holds the Collection) that one IsSelected/IsChecked (however you want to call it) State has changed. So that a PropertyChanged Event for PropertyName "AllSelected" will be raised.

The Collection Items ViewModel Property could look like this:

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return _isSelected; }
    set
    {
        _isSelected = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        ParentViewModel.RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
    }
}
```

Both CheckBoxes (The one in the Header Template and the one in the CellTemplate) are bind with `Mode=Twoway`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I fail to see what that value would be used for? I mean, the checkbox acts like a UI mechanism to select or unselect all the other boxes. But even if you actually need the value, why don't you bind it twoway to a ViewModel property?

Like this:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="headerCheckBox" Value="{Binding SelectAllCheckboxInTheViewModel}" />
```

Comment: Im using the value (true or false)  to update only the cheked data rows.

Comment: Why the Downvote? This is exactly what i also thought. You need the Value of each Rows CheckBox State, not the Header's Checkbox Value.

Comment: Yes, thats what i want, but i couldn't get the value of that checkbox.  How can i access it?

Comment: As he mentioned, you should bind the Value of the Rows Checkbox to a ViewModel Property.

Comment: Can u suggest a link or some way to do this. Im new to wpf.

Comment: zack> I didnt work, it gave an error "The member "Value" is not recognized or is not accessible"

Comment: I just described it a bit in a new Answer (Because of Code Examples and greater Text) If you are completly new to wpf, than this is a kind of more complex situation. You should start with the Basics like ViewModel/View Seperation via Binding. A good starting point is this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx?tduid=%2878e7a33c39030ba3f96386a5d812e508%29%28256380%29%282459594%29%28TnL5HPStwNw-1TE8k_HJii02BsPzyxNJFQ%29%28%29

Comment: Thank you, i will look in to it.