# select all checkbox binding in mvvm

Tags: wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I am working on 'Select All' checkbox in datagrid header in wpf using mvvm pattern. On clicking the checkbox, all the checkboxes gets checked and on uncheking it, the reverse happens.
But I am unable to fetch and bind the selected items to the View Model.

My code is like this

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Background="LightGray" CanUserAddRows="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dataGridCustomers" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UsecaseListItems}" CanUserResizeRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
             <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="headerCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding Path=MainWindowViewModel.AllSelected, Mode=TwoWay, 
              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Command="{Binding DoStuffCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=UserCaseListControl}"/>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Name="chkSelectAll" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=headerCheckBox, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UsecaseName}" Header="UsecaseName" IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

ViewModel is like:

```
    private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set
        {
            _IsSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    private bool _AllSelected;
    public bool AllSelected
    {
        get { return _AllSelected; }
        set
        {
            _AllSelected = value;
            foreach (var reportListItemModel in UsecaseListItems)
            {
                reportListItemModel.IsSelected = this._AllSelected;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("AllSelected");

        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<UseCase> _usecaseListItems = new ObservableCollection<UseCase>();
    public ObservableCollection<UseCase> UsecaseListItems
    {
        get { return _usecaseListItems; }
        set {
            _usecaseListItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UsecaseListItems");
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is the code to bind selected items ? what you do exactly want here ?

Comment: I want the slected checkbox values to be stored in a IEnumerable of strings in the view model

Comment: UsecaseListItems.Where(p=>p.IsSelected); --- is it something more than this ?

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999708/how-to-get-the-value-from-a-template-column-in-a-wpf-datagrid/37000291#37000291 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029133/select-all-checkbox-in-header-of-datagrid-and-its-binding-in-wpf-mvvm?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code, there will be no direct binding of selected items. As all your checkboxes were bind to `headerCheckBox.IsChecked`.

You could bind to your `UsecaseListItem.IsSelected` instead, and find another way to to execute `selectAll`:

e.g. Define the `UseCase` that inherit `ObservableObject` and use your above code in `AllSelected` to change each item's `IsSelected` property.

Or use a Command ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566050/executing-a-command-on-checkbox-checked-or-unchecked)) in your `headerCheckBox`.